# MongoDB: Iterate over collection by key?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, key

How can I iterate over all documents matching each value of a specified key in a MongoDB collection?

E.g. for a collection containing:

```
{ _id: ObjectId, keyA: 1 },
{ _id: ObjectId, keyA: 2 },
{ _id: ObjectId, keyA: 2 },
```

...with an index of `{ keyA: 1 }`, how can I run an operation on all documents where `keyA:1`, then `keyA:2`, and so on?

Specifically, I want to run a count() of the documents for each `keyA` value.  So for this collection, the equivalent of `find({keyA:1}).count()`, `find({keyA:2}).count()`, etc.

**UPDATE**: whether or not the keys are indexed is irrelevant in terms of how they're iterated, so edited title and description to make Q/A easier to reference in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach to get the grouped count of unique values for keyA would be to use the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2:

eg:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
  { $group : {
     _id: "$keyA",
     count: { $sum : 1 }
  }}
)
```

... returns a result set where each _id is a unique value for keyA, with the count of how many times that value appears:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this since it gets the job done and teaches me something new.  And accepting my own answer doesn't give anyone any more reputation... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I get you here but is this what you are looking for:

```
db.mycollection.find({ keyA: 1 }).count()
```

Will count all keys with `keyA` being 1.

If that does not answer the question do think you can be a little more specific?

Do you mean to do an aggregation for all unique key values for `keyA`?

Comment: Sorry, was having trouble expressing my question.  I mean to iterate over all the values present for the indexed key.  I'll edit my question to try to express that...

Comment: @ericsoco You might wanna look into the aggregation framework, I think this can do it.

Comment: @aleksey pointed me to distinct, which is within the aggregation framework.  thanks.

Comment: @ericsoco Aye provided your result set is smaller than a single document (16meg) :)

Comment: @ericsoco: While `distinct` is a command for aggregation, it is not the same as the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2, which takes a "pipeline" approach to finding and transforming results.

Comment: @Stennie That is true and I guess it is upto his need really, though the new aggregation framework might be better, I personally have not tested the two in such a scenario so I have no idea which performs better.

Comment: @ericsoco Actually now that I take a second look at the problem and stennies answer his is actually better probably.

Answer (score 1):

It may be implemented with multiple queries:

```
var i=0;
var f=[];
while(i!=db.col.count()){
  var k=db.col.findOne({keyA:{$not:{$in:f}}}).keyA;
  i+=db.col.find({keyA:k}).count();
  f.push(k);
}
```

The sense of this code is to collect unique values of *KeyA* field of objects of *col* collection in array f, which will be result of operation. Unfortunately, for a while doing this operation you should block any operations, which will change *col* collection.

**UPDATE:**

All can be done much easier using [distinct](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct):

```
db.col.distinct("KeyA")
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but it seems like overkill...wondering if there's a way to get the `values()` for the specified key, and then iterate over the documents matching each value, to use a more Java-style idiom...

Comment: This method seems like the ultimate inefficiency.

Comment: I think this will be faster than iterate via every element.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Aleksey for pointing me to [`db.collection.distinct`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct).

Looks like this does it:

```
db.ships.distinct("keyA").forEach(function(v){
    db.ships.find({keyA:v}).count();
});
```

Of course calling count() within a loop doesn't do much; in my case I was looking for key-values with more than one document, so I did this:

```
db.ships.distinct("keyA").forEach(function(v){
    print(db.ships.find({keyA:v}).count() > 1);
});
```